# "Resource not available" message for an applicarion created with spring roo

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

Hi i'm an absolute beginner in spring roo.I followed a tutorial on web and created a sample roo application. When i run the application using tomcat it always gives the message "The requested resource (/phonebook) is not available." i have mentioned the commands i entered in roo shell. can someone please tell me, why i'm getting that message?

```
project phonebook
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY    
entity jpa --class Contact    
field string --fieldname name    
field string --fieldName mobile    
web mvc setup    
web mvc all --package ~.web    
quit

mvn tomcat:run
```

Comment: What is the URL you are entering in the browser? Have you looked at the console output for tomcat (or $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out) - there might be useful info there.

Comment: The URL is http://localhost:8080/phonebook

Comment: and also there are no any errors in the console output for tomcat..

Comment: Can you try `persistence setup` instead of `jpa setup` and report back?